# Use a callback in a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, google-maps, oop, callback

Currently I'm working on a website with an OOP, class-based, JavaScript structure. Beneath is how I implemented the Google Maps API:

```
class MapView extends Module {
  constructor(element, $) {
    super();
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.initMap();
  }

  initMap() {
    if ( !$('#gmaps-api').length ) {
      var api = 'AIzaSyAfPMecz3Pl6eh5zysrdqbPuyoVImSCYTg';
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + api + '&callback=renderMap';
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.id = 'gmaps-api';
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
    }
  }

  renderMap() {
    console.log('called back');
  }
}
```

There are a few callbacks I already tried; like `MapView.renderMap` or just `renderMap`. How would I able to call the `renderMap()` function that's inside the `MapView` class, so I can execute some calls that render Google Maps on my page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Callback function that is going to be invoked by maps script once it's available, must be a global function. That's why you can't specify `MapView` instance method using `callback` GET parameter.

What you can however do is to create global reference to necessary method. Something like this should work:

```
window.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
```

Here is complete snippet:

```
class MapView extends Module {
  constructor(element, $) {
    super();
    this.$element = $(element);
    this.initMap();
  }

  initMap() {
    if (!$('#gmaps-api').length) {

      window.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);

      var api = 'AIzaSyAfPMecz3Pl6eh5zysrdqbPuyoVImSCYTg';
      var s = document.createElement('script');
      s.src = '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + api + '&callback=renderMap';
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.id = 'gmaps-api';
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
    }
  }

  renderMap() {
    console.log('called back');
  }
}
```